# Compilation error with std::is_same and operator ||

Tags: c++11, g++, clang++

I don't understand why the following code compiles with Clang++, but not with g++.

```
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

template <typename Base, typename T>
inline bool isInstanceOf(const T& object) {
    // This line compiles with clang++ (7.0.1) and with gcc (8.3.1)
    // return std::is_same<Base, T>::value ? true : (dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr);

    // This line compiles only with clang++
    return std::is_same<Base, T>::value || dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
}

int main() {
    isInstanceOf<A>(B());
    isInstanceOf<A>(A());   // Compilation fails

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error:

```
$> g++ -o bin -Wall -Werror test.cpp
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'bool isInstanceOf(const T&) [with Base = A; T = A]':
test.cpp:24:24:   required from here
test.cpp:19:79: error: the compiler can assume that the address of 'object' will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
  std::is_same<Base, T>::value || dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Why the template instanciation don't skip the second part of the test?

The following code also compiles:

```
if (std::is_same<Base, T>::value) {
    return true;
} else {
    return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
}
```

The compilation of the following code fails too:

```
if (std::is_same<Base, T>::value) {
    return true;
}

return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

(this is not an 'true' answer, but using an answer is more practical than using a remark)

I have the same behavior with your code but strangely there is no warning/error replacing

> ```
> return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
> ```

by

```
const T * pobject = &object;

return std::is_same<Base, T>::value || dynamic_cast<const Base*>(pobject) != nullptr;
```

---

```
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

template <typename Base, typename T>
inline bool isInstanceOf(const T& object) {
  const T * pobject = &object;

  return std::is_same<Base, T>::value || dynamic_cast<const Base*>(pobject) != nullptr;
}

int main() {
    isInstanceOf<A>(B());
    isInstanceOf<A>(A());   // Compilation fails

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation (gcc version 6.3.0)

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -Werror b.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Probably the compiler is just not looking far enough through its AST to decipher the fact that `pobject` comes from a `&` of the same type.  A reference is not _supposed_ to be null, whereas a pointer certainly may be...

Answer (score 0):

This code is not giving you an error, but a *warning.*  In my opinion, it's being helpful here.  Warnings are something you could elect to disregard, but in this case, it's making a helpful point: `dynamic_cast`ing a type to its base class will never return a `NULL`, and since this is a reference type, the compiler expects it is not a `NULL` pointer when you take the address of it.

This code:

```cpp
if (std::is_same<Base, T>::value) {
    return true;
} else {
    return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
}
```

...compiles because now you're introducing a situation where `dynamic_cast` may indeed return you a `NULL`, as the cast to `Base` may not be possible.  It's correct that G++ did not warn you here.

To me, this is a situation where GCC is giving you more complete warnings than Clang, not a situation where GCC is being deficient, telling you about code that won't execute under certain template instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

The following code also compile without warnings:

```cpp
template <typename Base, typename T>
bool isInstanceOf(const T& object) {
    if (!std::is_same<Base, T>::value) {
        return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
    }
}
```

Or this one:

```cpp
template <typename Base, typename T>
inline bool isInstanceOf(const T* pointer) {
    return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(pointer) != nullptr;
}

template <typename Base, typename T>
inline bool isInstanceOf(const T& object) {
    return std::is_same<Base, T>::value || isInstanceOf<Base>(&object);
}
```

@cyberbisson: you probably right, it should be a lack in the code analysis done by GCC.

I'm not sure what is the best syntax to solve my issue (or the more readable / understandable). The "if/else" option causes an issue with clang-tidy ([readability-else-after-return](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-else-after-return.html))

Currently I chose the "ternary operator" variant, but I like the "two functions" one.

Answer (score 0):

I think a c++17 solution works as well

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<Base, T>::value) {
  return true;
} else {
  return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(&object) != nullptr;
}
```